# Change Global Search Box Colour in Community Cloud

Tags: community, global-search, community-cloud

I would like to change the colour of the Global Search Box in the Community Cloud. I've tried some CSS, but they do not work.

.actualNode{ color:white; }
.slds-input{ color:white; }
.inputWrapper{ color:white; }
.contentWrapper{ color:white; }

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the builder, in Theme you need to Edit CSS (Use Overrides)

[image: Edit CSS]

and then paste this CSS:

.slds-global-header__item--search {
background-color: blue;
}

.slds-global-header__item--search .slds-input {
color:white;
}

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would want to [Build a Custom Search Component](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communities_theme_layout/custom_search) and apply your styling within the component's scope.

**Why?**

Because template selectors are subject to change with future releases. If you override the CSS through the editor, there is no guarantee that it will work in future releases.

Same goes for most, if not all css modifications in the editor for community changes.